# Sort words from n rows

Tags: bash, files, scripting, sort

i need to print all the unique words and their occurences from first n rows in a give file. I have to sorted by their number of occurences and then alphabetically.(the only separator is " ") ex:
for the following 5 rows:

> hei hei hei hei hei
>
> hello hello
>
> aa aa
>
> b b
>
> a

I will print

> hei 5
>
> aa 2
>
> b 2
>
> hello 2
>
> a 1

So far my script is :

```
tr -c [:space:] '\n' <$1|head -n $number_of_rows| sort |uniq -c|sort -k1rn -k2n|awk '{print $2,$1}'
```

Comment: You want `tr -s`  not `tr -c`. Check the `tr` man page

Comment: @glennjackman  that is how i've tried  the first time..the output is even worse..

Comment: And you have to put `head` at the front of the pipeline if you want "the first n rows of the file", since the `tr` call destroys the meaning of "rows"

Answer (score 1):

If you know that each line consists of a single word repeated a number of times, you can do:

```
awk -v n=$number_of_rows '
    NR == n+1 {exit} 
    {print $1, NF}
' file | sort -k2,2rn -k1,1
```

Comment: i don't know that..